# Detect a loop in a linked list,regarding slow and fast pointer

Tags: linked-list

My question is why both slow_ptr and fast_ptr pointers are checked whether they are NULL or not to see if there exists a loop or not whereas we can do it only by checking the fast_ptr is NULL or not, as fast_ptr moves faster than slow_ptr.

code link:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-length-of-loop-in-linked-list/

```
int countNodesinLoop(struct Node *list)  
{  
    struct Node *slow_p = list, *fast_p = list;  

    //in this part
    while (slow_p && fast_p &&  
                     fast_p->next)  
    {  
        slow_p = slow_p->next;  
        fast_p = fast_p->next->next;  

        /* If slow_p and fast_p meet at  
        some point then there is a loop */
        if (slow_p == fast_p)  
            return countNodes(slow_p);  
    }  

    /* Return 0 to indeciate that  
       their is no loop*/
    return 0;  
}
```